# How to Install 'libharu' library in Visual Studio 2013 version?

Tags: c++, libharu

I am working on converting files to PDF using C++, I downloaded the libharu files from its website but do not know what to do next. 
I am unable to use the command "nmake -f script/Makefile.msvc".

Comment: What error did you face ? Nmake cmd not recognize ?